# Разбор BMP изображения

Tags: perl

Разобрал заголовок. По этой табличке всё расписал.

```
http://c-site.h1.ru/infa/bmp_struct.htm
```

Но вот неясно, размер заголовка BITMAP по идее должен быть 40, а у меня 108. Это значит, что в этом промежутке BITMAPV5HEADER? Я решил не тормозить долго за заголовком, а попутно начать разбирать изображение. В массиве @header лежат все заголовочки по порядку (как в первой ссылке) заголовка файла и заголовка BITMAP. $header[1] - размер файла в байтах, $header[4] - смещение, с которого начинается изображение. Мое изображение 32-х битное, а значит не имеет палитры и 4 байта определяют 3 компоненты BGR и Alpha. Конкретно мое изображение имеет размер 48х48, поэтому я решил разобрать 1 строку (код Perl):

```
read (BMP, $data, $header[1]-$header[4], $header[4]); 
@image = unpack("C192", $data); 
print "@image";
```

На консоль вот что вывело.

> http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=6126fbac69c18fb308cd8d7b5d109595

Хотя я делаю разбор вот такой картинки:

```
http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=26c569e841b17e84d624b377ac9aab82 <br>
```

И вот вопрос: моя ошибка в неправильной трактовке, неверном понимании формата или в незнании языка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно просто посмотреть как происходит обработка BMP файлов в пакете [Image::BMP](http://search.cpan.org/~daveola/Image-BMP-1.16/lib/Image/BMP.pm) ?

**UPDATE**: 2011-10-14 18:26

Если все делать "руками" то получается примерно такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w --

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fh = IO::File->new( $ARGV[0] );

$fh->binmode(":bytes");

my %header;
unless ($fh->sysread($_, 2)) {
    die "Error read first 2 bytes of file";
}
( $header{bfType} ) = unpack("A2");

if ($header{bfType} ne 'BM') {
    die "Invalid file header";
}
unless ($fh->sysread($_, 12)) {
    die "Error read BMP header";
}
( $header{bfSize}, $header{bfOffset} ) = unpack("Lx2x2L");

if ($header{bfSize} != ($fh->stat)[7]) {
    die "Invalid BMP file size";
}
print Dumper \%header;

my %bitmap;

unless ($fh->sysread($_, 4)) {
    die "Error read BITMAP length of BMP file";
}
( $bitmap{biSize} ) = unpack("l");

unless ($fh->sysread($_, $bitmap{biSize} - 4)) {
    die "Error read BITMAP of BMP file";
}
(
    $bitmap{biWidth},
    $bitmap{biHeight},
    $bitmap{biPlanes},
    $bitmap{biBitCount},
    $bitmap{biCompression},
    $bitmap{biSizeImage},
    $bitmap{biXPelsPerMeter},
    $bitmap{biYPelsPerMeter},
    $bitmap{biClrUsed},
    $bitmap{biClrImportant}
) = unpack("llSSLLllLL");

print Dumper \%bitmap;

my @palette;
if ($bitmap{biClrUsed} > 0) {
    unless ($fh->sysread($_, 4 * $bitmap{biClrUsed})) {
        die "Error read palette of BMP file";
    }
    @palette = map { sprintf("%08X", $_) } unpack("L" x $bitmap{biClrUsed});
    print Dumper \@palette; 
}
# Read file here...
unless ($fh->seek( $header{bfOffset}, 0 )) {
    die "Invalid bfOffset in header found";
}

my @data;
my $row_bytes_length = (4 * int(($bitmap{biBitCount} * $bitmap{biWidth} + 4) / 4)) / 8;

for (my $row = $bitmap{biHeight} - 1; $row >= 0; $row--) {
    if ($fh->sysread($_, $row_bytes_length)) {
        $data[ $row ] = [];

        for (my $col = 0; $col < $bitmap{biWidth}; $col++ ) {
            my $pixel = vec ($_, $col, $bitmap{biBitCount});

            push (@{ $data[ $row ] }, scalar(@palette) ?
                ($palette[$pixel] || "{xUNDEF}") :
                sprintf("%08X", $pixel)
            );
        }
    }
    else {
        die "Error reading image data";
    }
}
print Dumper \@data;
```

Comment: в этом пакете только разбор заголовка, однако мне нужен попиксельный разбор растра, самого изображения, чтобы потом его вывести

Comment: Почему, там есть методы xy которые позволяют выяснить цвет конкретного пикселя. Потом есть add_pixel:

    sub my_add {
        my ($img,$x,$y,$r,$g,$b) = @_;
        print "add pixel $x,$y = $r,$g,$b\n";
    }
    my $img = new Image::BMP(file => 'some.bmp', add_pixel = \&my_add);
    $img->load;

С помощью которого можно просто обработать весь файл.

Comment: А если есть желание написать свой обработчик, то начало может выглядеть примерно так см.: https://gist.github.com/1286725